# Vuejs : how to dynamically update value of variable

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli

im newbie here, I want to update the day variable value, this will be implemented in the vuejs-datepicker, it looks like the image below :

[image]

This is my code :

```
data() {
    var day = null
    
    var state = {
        disabledDates: {
            days: [day], // 0,1 (value of the day)
        }
    }
    return {

        state: state,
        day: day,
    }
},
watch: {
    'day': function(day){
        console.log('day: '+day)
        return this.day
    },
},
```

This is my expected image, after the value of the day is 0,1 :

[image]

Thanks..

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. You say you want to _"update the day variable"_ but you never assign it a value other than `null`. Are you using it in a `v-model` or something like that? What is the point of your watcher? What is `state` for? It's never used

Comment: wait, i want update my code

Comment: state is used in the vuejs-datepicker library

Comment: I am not using v-model, but i want to change the value of day of watch

Comment: Then how do you change the value of the day variable
`days: [day]`

Comment: How would you be expecting to change the `day` value? Should there be some UI component or form that controls it?

Comment: yes, after I chose doctor, the value of day is filled in. I handle it from the method, as you can see on the console, the value of day has changed

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to control the days passed into the date-picker `disabledDates`.

For this, I would use an array of days (0-6) and create a computed property for the date-picker config

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({ days: [0, 1] }), // or whatever makes sense as a default value
  computed: {
    state: ({ days }) => ({
      disabledDates: { days }
    })
  }
}
```

You can control the `days` property however you want. For example, using checkboxes

```html
<label v-for="(day, index) in ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']" :key="index">
  {{ day }}
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="days" :value="index">
</label>
```